# Intellij, change maven version of maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project but my version of maven is very old (3.3.9). So, I wanted to change the version to the 3.8.6 in the parameters (settings/build, Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/Maven/Maven home path) were I add the binary folder of maven. But then, when I want to reload my project i get the following error :

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.model.validation.DefaultModelValidator: method 'void <init>()' not found
  at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator
  at ClassRealm[maven.ext, parent: ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.model.validation.ModelValidator annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value="ide")

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.model.validation.ModelValidator
  roleHint: ide
```

and when I relaunch intellij nothing happens when I reload the project..

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: which intellij version are you using?

Comment: 2021.3.2 (Community Edition), I can't upgrade intellij though, since my company does not allow it

Comment: Have you downloaded the Maven binary and stored them on your machine? The way you describe it makes it feel as if you just changed the settings.
What happens when you open a command line and execute 'mvn --version' ?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290419 . You need to update the IDE build to 2022.1 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download .